# RS.GetValue(RS.GetOrdinal("balance")) produces an unexpected value

Tags: mysql, vb.net, decimal

I'm using Visual Studio 2005 along with mysql 4.0, i have a table with a field (decimal 16,4) that stores the amount of an invoice and another table with the payments to this invoice (the fields are also decimal 16,4)

I read the data and get some records with 4 columns (invoice,amount,payments,balance)

```vb
invoice 454, Amount 8125.68 payments: 8125.68 balance : 0
```

The payments come from a sum(payments) statement.

The data of records from the related payments are : 8122.16, 0.0900, 0.0050, 1.6900, 1.7350

the total is 8125.68

I read data like this :

```vb
Dim Conn As New MySqlConnection(myConnString)
Dim RS As MySqlDataReader
dim Q as string="SELECT.........." ' MYSQL STATEMENT

Dim CM As New MySqlCommand(Q, Conn)

RS = CM.ExecuteReader

While RS.Read
   RS.GetValue(RS.GetOrdinal("invoice")) 
   RS.GetValue(RS.GetOrdinal("amount")) 
   RS.GetValue(RS.GetOrdinal("payments")) 
   RS.GetValue(RS.GetOrdinal("balance")) 
End While
```

And Everything works fine but the value of this:

```vb
RS.GetValue(RS.GetOrdinal("balance"))
```

is `0.000000009456544`, instead of `0.00`! What's going on here?

Comment: Instead of GetValue have you tried GetDecimal?

Comment: Looks like a floating point arithmetic error http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [floating number precision accuracy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems)

Comment: The first `Related` topic to the right is [`MySQL calculation issues 1+1 = 1.9999999`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1202693/62576). Did you read it?

Comment: Thanks for the clue. now i know where to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think `DECIMAL` used `DOUBLE` back in the dark ages of MySQL 4.0.  Hence the screwy results and the comments.

(Answering in order to remove from Unanswered.)